# Can a browser execute "on close" WebSocket event when closing the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

When a browser or tab is closed, I have a small snippet that sends an `XHttpRequest` to a given endpoint to signal that the WebSocket connection has been dropped abnormally.

```
wsConnection.onclose = function(event) {
  axios.post('/state', { reason: 'abnormal' });
};
```

Is there a guarantee that the browser will execute the event on a tab/window close? If not, then how do I detect the "client disconnected forcefully"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't even guarantee that your ajax call is executed (for example crash or internet connection dropped).

You should use `client.ping()` on the server-side to detect if a client has a connection loss. WebSocket-Clients are forced by [RFC 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) to answer to ping-requests by the server.

If the status-code is 1006, the [connection was closed abnormal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#page-46).